# Why is mysql_real_escape_string causing no results to be obtained by these SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following queries yield no results:

A)

```
$Part = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Part']);

$part_query = "SELECT title FROM tag WHERE title LIKE '$Part%'";
```

B)

```
$Part = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['Part']));

$part_query = "SELECT title FROM tag WHERE title LIKE '$Part%'";
```

**While this does:** (EDIT: This does NOT work either)

C)

```
$Part = $_POST['Part'];

$part_query = "SELECT title FROM tag WHERE title LIKE '$Part%'";
```

How do I get around this?  I certainly have to escape form input.

D)

This works:

```
$Part = $_POST['Part'];
$Part = strip_tags($Part,"");
$Part = trim($Part);
$part_query = "SELECT title FROM tag WHERE title LIKE '$Part%'";
```

Comment: what does echo $_POST['Part']; display? Maybe the formdata is already escaped with MagicQuotes

Comment: var_dump($_POST['Part']); please

Comment: var_dump $part_query for each scenario and post results, I'm betting magic quotes is getting you.

Comment: a var_dump for "great" gives string(5) "great" in each case...nothing weird there...See the edit in the question though!

Comment: `addslashes` are redundant here.

Comment: strip_tags() is designed to work on HTML. What does HTML have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works, if so you are getting bit by magic quotes, and at least with the global strip you know they have been removed.

```
<?php
// Remove magic quotes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  function stripslashes_deep($value){
    $value = is_array($value)?array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value):stripslashes($value);
    return $value;
  }
  $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
  $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
  $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
  $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
}
// Format and prepare SQL
$Part = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Part']);
$part_query = "SELECT `title` FROM `tag` WHERE `title` LIKE '$Part%'";

// obviously update below for your connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'world'); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
   printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server. Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
   exit; 
} 
if ($result = $mysqli->query($part_query)) { 
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ 
        print(json_encode(($row))); 
    }
    $result->close(); 
} 
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Just a note: Your `stripslashes_deep` doesn’t unescape the keys.

Comment: True, but I've not a case where the keys ever got escaped, so hadn't thought about that "feature" :)

Answer (score 0):

trim removes leading and trailing white-spaces from the string, does this work:

```
$Part = trim($_POST['Part']);
$Part = mysql_real_escape_string($Part);
$part_query = "SELECT title FROM tag WHERE title LIKE '$Part%'";
```